# Why system call stubs in NewLib are needed only on Linux and not on Windows?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, newlib

I have a project in MCUXpresso with a custom linker file. The project builds fine on Windows but it fails on Linux. On Linux, the linker fails with the following error (the compiler paths are shortened):

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-abort.o): in function `abort':
abort.c:(.text.abort+0xa): undefined reference to `_exit'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_kill'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): undefined reference to `_getpid'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_write'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_close'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_fstat'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_isatty'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_lseek'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m/nofp/libc_nano.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_read'
```

The linker file originally "includes" the following static libraries:

```
GROUP (
  "libgcc.a"
  "libc_nano.a"
  "libm.a"
  "libcr_newlib_none.a"
)
```

Now, I can get the linker successfully do its job by adding `"libnosys.a"` to the GROUP statement. That's where it gets confusing for me. Why do these new stubs in libnosys.a are needed only on Linux? How and where are they defined in Windows? What am I missing?

GCC version on my Windows and Linux are `8.3.1` and `10.2.1`, respectively, as they come bundled with different versions of MCUXpresso.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The libraries for Windows and Linux include different implementations of the standard functions, I think. As you see in the error messages, all missed function are really low level. The Windows implementations might not need them because they can directly call Win32 API functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any documentation to confirm that?

Comment: What does the documentation of your used "libc" (nano) say? BTW, what are your targets, native Linux and Windows, or are you cross-compiling?

Answer (score 0):

So I did more investigation and found out that this problem has nothing to do with Linux vs Windows. The issue was related to different versions of MCUXpresso. Furthermore, the `libcr_newlib_none` library is unique to MCUXpresso and is not available in the original GCC.

Anyway, something seems to be broken in MCUXpresso 11.4.1. I have created [a question](https://community.nxp.com/t5/LPC-Microcontrollers/Why-system-call-stubs-in-NewLib-are-needed-only-on-Linux-and-not/m-p/1342047/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEtUTzNEN1pTUTdWM0VUfDEzNDIwNDd8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw) on NXP's forums to further follow up the issues with them.